# How can I create two dropdowns with dependency in a Google spreadsheet without using a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a Google sheet you can easily create a dropdown list based on a range of cells using menu **Data** => **Data validation**. I now need two dropdowns that have a dependency: the first one lists programs, the second one lists projects of the selected program. Here is how it currently looks:

[image: Screenshot of sheet with dropdowns]

How can I add a filter to the range to show only projects of the selected program?

Instead of a range I can specify a formula in the data validation dialog box. I tried custom formula `=QUERY(D2:E12, "Select E where D = """&B2&""" ")`, but that does not create a dropdown.

Short test data, the actual table has 700+ rows:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  | Programs: | Projects: |
| 2 | Program: | P2 |  | P1 | P1 Design |
| 3 | Project: |  |  | P1 | P1 Coding |
| 4 |  |  |  | P1 | P1 Testing |
| 5 |  |  |  | P1 | P1 Integration |
| 6 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Design |
| 7 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Coding |
| 8 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Testing |
| 9 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Design |
| 10 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Coding |
| 11 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 SVT |
| 12 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Ops |

Comment: @doubleunary: Thanks, but I was looking for (and found) a way with just formulas, and no scripts

Comment: @isherwood: Thanks. I made the title more specific, `without using a scrip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. The trick is to use yet another column F that has a query listing the projects of the selected program, then in the Project data validation, specify the range in column F:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  | Programs: | Projects: | Selected Projects: |
| 2 | Program: | P2 |  | P1 | P1 Design | P2 Design |
| 3 | Project: | P2 Testing |  | P1 | P1 Coding | P2 Coding |
| 4 |  |  |  | P1 | P1 Testing | P2 Testing |
| 5 |  |  |  | P1 | P1 Integration |  |
| 6 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Design |  |
| 7 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Coding |  |
| 8 |  |  |  | P2 | P2 Testing |  |
| 9 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Design |  |
| 10 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Coding |  |
| 11 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 SVT |  |
| 12 |  |  |  | P3 | P3 Ops |  |

Formula in F2: `=QUERY(D2:E12, "Select E where D = """&B2&""" ")`